# Try to note if value in one column is equal to the value in the next column per row

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am fairly new to R and trying to count the number of fish moves so I can do a chi-squared test by month.

Each row is a fish, each column is a month, if the fish are detected in a given month its value is the location it was detected, if it was not detected in that month, it has a value of 0. If it is detected in multiple locations, the value has both location in the order they were detected in that month.

```
Tag_ID    Region.Init 2017-05-01  2017-06-01 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01

1 326000       Lower          0        Upper         0          0       Misc       
2 326001       Lower          0 Lower, Misc       Misc          0          0          
3 326002       Lower          0       Lower          0          0          0
```

I am trying to note the months the fish arrived at new locations. Whether the months this occurs is put into a new column or they are noted somehow in the data, doesn't matter. So, I tried to do a nested loop where it ran through each row and if the column was equal to the next it would change the second value to a 1, however this altered the next loop as the value is now different. I also ran into the problem of R thinking that when the value changes to 0(aka not detected), it is a movement, which is not what I want. The other problem I encountered was when there was multiple locations (Eg Lower,Misc) and the next month was the second of those (Misc) it would count the jump between the two as a move, when the fish actually stayed in Misc.

Ideally, I want the dataset to look something like this:

```
Tag_ID    Region.Init 2017-05-01  2017-06-01 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01 Moves

1 326000    Lower        0          Upper          0          0       Misc     2017-06-01, 2017-09-01  
2 326001    Lower        0    Lower, Misc       Misc          0          0      2017-06-01    
3 326002    Lower        0          Lower          0          0          0        NA
```

Comment: What are all possible values like `Upper`, `Lower, Misc`, `Lower`, etc.?

Comment: All possible values are Upper, Lower, Misc then all combinations of these, so (Upper, Misc), (Upper, Lower), (Lower, Upper), (Misc, Upper), (Lower, Misc), (Misc, Lower), but also (Upper, Lower, Misc), (Upper, Misc, Lower), (Lower, Upper, Misc), (Lower, Misc, Upper), (Misc, Upper, Lower). (Misc, Lower, Upper)

Comment: So including what I wrote above, I should consider `Upper, Misc`, `Middle`, `Middle,Misc`, and `Misc` ?

Comment: sorry that first comment was a typo, the one that I just posted is correct

Comment: And you want to detect if there is a difference between a "0" and some other values besides "Lower"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to work on a dataset with columns tag, date, location?

Comment: @KarstenW. but then each detection would be seperated and thus multiple detections of the same fish wouldnt be identified so I wouldnt be able to identify movement.

Comment: @akash87 no sorry for the confusion, I am trying to identify when the location changes and ignore the "0"s because all they are is an absence of data. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Then why is the third row NA at ‘moves’?

Comment: @akash87 because the fish is detected at Lower and no other sites, so the fish doesnt move between sites

Comment: @KateCharmley you could subset on tag and would have all movements of one specific fish. Order this subset by date and you have its movements. The point I want to make: try to normalize your data, make it look more like a entity-relationship model. Then it will be much easier to answer most questions you have on your data.